# How to create separate tasks for building and running c++ code in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I feel like this should have been very straightforward but googling leads me to various blogposts with no direct answer.

I want to have a few different build tasks:

1) Just Build with debugging on

2) Build with debugging off

3) Run the binary output file

4) Build with debugging off and run the binary output file.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "Build with Clang and Debugging",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "clang++",
        "args": [
          "-std=c++11",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "helloworld.cpp",
          "-o",
          "helloworld.out",
          "--debug"
        ],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      },
      {
        "label": "Build with Clang without Debugging",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "clang++",
        "args": [
          "-std=c++11",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "helloworld.cpp",
          "-o3",
          "helloworld.out"
        ],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I am not sure how to create the above tasks and run them. I tried creating a new task for building without debugging and there seems to be a syntax error. I also want to just run (by a keyword shortcut) without manually typing for instance, `./helloworld.out` on the terminal.

And the `"isDefault": false` seems to be giving me some syntax error.

Is there a way to have all these tasks and assign a keyboard shortcut to each of them?